# Aggregation on an attribute which could be null

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate attributes from two collections, one of those contains a field which may or may not be there in a document. When the attribute is not there in the document it doesn't return any document at all. So I need to create a kind of null check, that if the attribute is not there don't consider the attribute else consider it, below is my query -

```
db.collection(collectionName).aggregate(
      [{
        $match: selector
      }, {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'status',
          localField: 'candidateId',
          foreignField: 'candidateId',
          as: 'profile'
        }
      }, {
        $project: {
          '_id': 0,

          'currentStatus': '$profile.currentStatus',
          'lastContacted': '$profile.lastContacted',
          'lastWorkingDay': '$profile.lastWorkingDay',
          'remarks': '$profile.remarks'
        }
      },{
         $unwind: '$lastWorkingDay'
      }
```

In this case `lastWorkingDay` if not present makes the whole query return nothing. Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something else is wrong with your query. 
This is a bit hard to analyse without any data input, so I made up my own:

I have tried this on my local box just now, and it executes the way you'd expect it.

A projection shouldn't remove any kind of results. Here is my example:

Collection c1:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c780eea79e5bed2bd00f85e"),
    "candidateId" : "id1",
    "currentStatus" : "a",
    "lastContacted" : "b"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c780efb79e5bed2bd00f863"),
    "candidateId" : "id2",
    "currentStatus" : "a",
    "lastContacted" : "b",
    "lastWorkingDay" : "yesterday"
}
```

Collection C2:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c780f0a79e5bed2bd00f874"),
    "candidateId" : "id1"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c780f2879e5bed2bd00f87b"),
    "candidateId" : "id2"
}
```

Aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('c2').aggregate( [
    {$match: {}},
    { $lookup: {
            from: "c1",
            localField: "candidateId",
            foreignField: "candidateId",
            as : "profile"

        } },
    {$project: {
            _id: 0,
        "currentStatus" : "$profile.currentStatus",
        "lastWorkingDay" : "$profile.lastWorkingDay"

        } }

] )
```

Results:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "currentStatus" : [ 
        "a"
    ],
    "lastWorkingDay" : []
}

/* 2 */
{
    "currentStatus" : [ 
        "a"
    ],
    "lastWorkingDay" : [ 
        "yesterday"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the lastWorkingDay is executed correctly for both values in my aggregation.

Note that the lookup is creating an array for `profiles` since there could be multiple results for the lookup. You may need to `unwind` this if you need it in more detail.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct, I am doing unwind, but in case `lastContacted` date is null the unwind fails and thus the result is always null. Need to handle that I have updated the question after analysis.

Comment: cool - i think your question has already been answered then and linked on the top :)

Comment: Yes, I found that answer and marked my question as duplicate, since I couldn't delete it due to people put effort :)